# Cannot obtain Kovan testnet Ether

Tags: ether, testnets, kovan

Does anyone else have issues obtaining kovan ether? I have tried the following links only to recieve 0.01 Keth increments from app.mycrypto.com (when the site is up). The github sites do not respond
https://gitter.im/kovan-testnet/faucet
https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet/issues/128
https://github.com/kovan-testnet/faucet/issues
https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet
https://faucet.kovan.network/ returns "this site can't be reached"

I need KETH to debug issues with running a personal project that works locally. Happy to pay (nominal amounts) for KETH as obtaining KETH is too time consuming.
Is the Kovan network to be avoided due to this problem? Would it be less troublesome to test directly on the mainnet?

Comment: Side note: if you have a local project, why do you try to get eth on Kovan ?

Comment: I want to take it (eventually) to mainnet. ganache does not run the same as testnets as they are breaking my code (it does not break locally)

Answer (score 1):

Yeah as Scorpion said - MyCrypto's Faucet pumps a little out. However you can also email us - support@mycrypto.com if you need a little more. We have a tip jar too if you want to drop a thank you for the testnet eth.

Thanks!

Comment: thanks again! I will be reaching out to mycrypto support!

Answer (score 1):

The testnets Kovan, Ropsten, and Rinkeby have been deprecated as a result of the recent Ethereum merge. Goerli is the sole Ethereum testnet at the moment.

Goerli testETH is available for free from Alchemy at https://goerlifaucet.com.

Btw if you want developer tools, they have pretty legit resources and a web3 course - https://docs.alchemy.com and https://university.alchemy.com/

Answer (score 0):

You could instead use MyCrypto's faucet. It supports Rinkeby, Ropsten, Kovan, and Goerli testnets. Just switch your Metamask to the intended testnet and then visit the following URL to receive your test ETH:
https://app.mycrypto.com/faucet

Comment: thanks for responding. I included mycrypto in my original letter . When the site is up ( frequently it is down....) I can obtain .01 increments. This is time consuming and not practical for my testing which has easily used that in less than a day.